# Performing a migration to a 2012 FL Active Directory domain/forest?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, migration

I'm looking to perform a migration of an existing 2008 R2 Active Directory forest to a new(ish) 2012 forest, and bumped into the issue that there don't seem to be any compatible tools to do so.  The latest version of ADMT (v3.2) isn't supported in a 2012 FL environment, and failed to actually do anything once I got it installed in the 2008 R2 domain and tried to migrate a test user.

Looking online, I found a not-exactly-helpful Technet article saying that ADMT 3.2 doesn't support 2012, and my workaround is to install a 2008 R2 domain controller, demote the domain, migrate and then decommission the 2008 R2 domain controller and elevate domain back to 2012, which is pretty %@!#ing ridiculous.

Given that, has anyone performed a migration to a 2012 FL domain/forest and/or have any non-ridiculous suggestions on how to go about it?

Worst-case, I figure I can punch something up in PowerShell, but given that it's 2014, I'm finding the lack of support for 2012 a little confusing and am holding out hope that I'm just missing something here.

Comment: Hey Hopeless, good to see you again.  I know you already know, but for others, I'm linking the KB article that describes your issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2753560

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft has published a blog post somewhere that I can't find at the moment stating that a new version of ADMT will be released in Q1 of 2014 that will support installation on, and migration to/from, any currently supported version of Windows Server. So, you have three options:

1. Shell out cash for Quest tools which don't have this restriction
2. Install a 2008 R2 DC in your 2012 environment. Lowering the DFL/FFL isn't terribly difficult and the only features you really lose are Kerberos armoring and CAP for file services. Note that you'll also need a 2008 R2 member server in the target domain to install ADMT on, unless you install it on a DC which generally isn't recommended.
3. Sit tight and wait for the next version of ADMT to drop.

Comment: Here's the link to the [blog post.](https://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2013/12/13/an-update-for-admt-and-a-few-other-things-too.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  That got me to the blog article that implies the new version of ADMT will work with 2012.

Comment: Re: #2 - Hope you haven't enabled any optional features, e.g. AD Recycle Bin.

Comment: @RyanRies the AD Recycle bin works at a 2008 R2 level, and shouldn't be effected by downgrading the DFL to 2008 R2, though.